# How to get the HTML code for the profile?

Tags: support

About a month back I received a notification from the site saying I can paste a code on an HTML page to showcase my profile and badges earned. I have lost that message. I need to get that code. How can it be done ?

Comment: Go to your profile, click edit profile & settings, then click flair, and you'll see the html codes for different flairs.